# Creating a Maven Artifact from (Eclipse) Project, and Generating New Project from it

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, artifact

I have an Maven (eclipse) Project, which i want to convert to an Maven Artifact - so that others can generate new Project from it.

**To create Artifact i did:**
cd to my proj dir where pom.xml exists

```
mvn install
```

After this i can see that
.m2\repository has my project added.
**But** <user_home>\.m2\archetype-catalog.xml - did not have the archetype added.
So, i added manually as follows:

```
<archetype>
      <groupId>com.whatever</groupId>
      <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <repository></repository>
</archetype>
```

Now, i am not sure what to give in  tag, as this is a local repository.

But, i am unable to generate a new project using:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local
```

It asks me to choose the archetype, but after that i get error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2
.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does
not exist (com.whatever:myapp:1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT) -> [Help 1]

*What step am i missing?*

Comment: This issue is not related to "git"

Comment: Or Eclipse for that matter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to run the archetype plugin from within your original project to generate an archetype descriptor.

[Here is an example of how to do this.](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/create-from-project-mojo.html)

The complete steps are listed here:
http://hello-its-crazy.blogspot.in/2012/08/steps-to-create-maven-archetype-from.html

Comment: codethulhu> So, as a first step now I did this successsfully: mvn archetype:create-from-project , and repeated all the steps mentioned in my question. I still have exact same problem.

Comment: Your second link is broken

Comment: The second link is broken.